# Where to store localization translations fetched from server in Angular?

Tags: angular

After first initialization Angular fetches the localization file with all translations.

Where to store this data in application for while execution application?
That I can load any translations by specified key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just in a json file in a i18n folder for example or read more here: https://angular.io/guide/i18n

Comment: I fetch this json from server, not local